# SQL - query inside NOT IN takes longer than the complete query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using NOT IN inside my SQL query.

For example:

```
select columnA 
from table1
where columnA not in (
select columnB
from table2)
```

How is it possible that this part of the query

```
select columnB
from table2
```

takes 30sec to complete, but the whole query above takes 0.1sec to complete?? 
Shouldn't the complete query take 30sec + ?

BTW, both queries return valid results.

Thanks!

**Answers to Comments**

> Is it because the second query hasn't
>   actually completed but has only
>   returned back the first 'x' rows (out
>   of a very large table?)

No, the query is completed after 30 seconds, not to many rows returned (eg. 50).

> But @Aleksandar wondered why the
>   question congaing the performance
>   killer was so fast.

my point exactly

> Also how long does select distinct
>   columnB from table2 take to execute?

actually, the original query is "select distinct...

Comment: Is it because the second query hasn't actually completed but has only returned back the first 'x' rows (out of a very large table?)

Comment: Is table2 extremely large since a normal select on a column takes 30 sec to complete?

Comment: What are the table definitions including FK relationships? Is it possible it is doing some clever optimisation based on these that mean it doesn't have to evaluate the inner query?

Comment: Also how long does `select distinct columnB from table2` take to execute?

Comment: Is it because the second query hasn't actually completed but has only returned back the first 'x' rows (out of a very large table?)

No, the query is completed after 30 seconds, not to many rows returned (eg. 50).

    But @Aleksandar wondered why the question congaing the performance killer was so fast.

my point exactly

    Also how long does select distinct columnB from table2 take to execute?

actually, the original query is "select distinct...

Comment: Can you look at the execution plans for both?

Comment: or better yet: Post both plans along with DDL for both tables.

Comment: rows returned is 50, how many when not using DISTINCT? your columnB should have an index so DISTINCT or GROUP BY could become performant

Comment: when not using distinct I get 400 rows with my query, table2 is actually many tables joined with millions of rows... But my question still remains the same, why a subquery is so much slower than the complete query...

Comment: @Aleksandar Tomic, the answer to your question lies in the details you refuse to give us. You need to realize that SQL is declarative by nature. You specify "what" you want, and let the database come up with an algorithm that solves it. Right now, the database is doing some funny stuff because of the underlaying details. Those details will be revealed if you show us the exact query, the explain plans from it, and the create script for all referenced tables.

Comment: will post explain plan later...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are thinking that your main query implies the following steps:

```
(1)  Run the subquery
(2)  Check each row in table1 against the result set from the subquery.
```

Therefore, you think that running the subquery separately must take less time than running the whole query.

But SQL is not a procedural language, and the structure of the query does not necessarily imply the steps that will be followed to execute the query.

As Guffa answered, the optimizer will come up with (what it believes is) an optimal plan to execute each query.  These execution plans are not always obvious from looking at the query, and in some cases can indeed be quite counter-intuitive.

I think that it is most likely, in this case, that the optimizer has come up with a quicker method for checking whether a value exists in table2 than simply querying all of table2 at once.  It could be the transformation Guffa showed (although that still does not tell you the exact execution plan being used).

I would guess that table1 has significantly fewer rows than table2, and an index exists on table2.columnB.  So all it has to do is fetch the rows from table1, then probe the index for each of those value to check for existence.  But this is only one possibility.

Also, as Michael Buen pointed out, differences in the size of the result set returned can also impact your perceived performance.  My intuition is that this is secondary to the execution plan differences, but it can be significant.

Comment: Your answer, and Michael's answer is pretty much what I was looking for. I didn't want someone to point exactly where the problem is (that's why I simplified the query), but an overall answer with few possibilities of how the above is possible. I have lots of other ways to make the subquery work faster, but I was wondering how a slow subquery "works a lot faster" when inside NOT IN (...). Thanks Dave, and thanks to all the others for their answers.

Answer (score 4):

It's because the query optimiser turns the query to something that looks completely different. The actual query should be the same as what's produced by a query like this:

```
select columnA 
from table1
left join table2 on ColumnA = ColumnB
where ColumnB is null
```

If the database can use indexes to join the tables, perhaps it doesn't have to query the entire table2, or even touch the table itself.

Comment: Wouldn't the comment about accessing an index rather than the base table apply equally well to the query `select columnB from table2`? Is there some kind of index in Oracle that would be suitable for one query but not the other?

Comment: Oracle can't apply that transformation if either columnA or columnB are nullable. NOT IN becomes a filter operation with subquery, whereas your query becomes a anti-jon (hash or nl)

Comment: @Martin: When you select everything from the table, the database has to access the entire table (or the entire index), but when you join it to another table, it might only have to access a small part of the table because the join elliminates most of the records.

Comment: @Ronnis: Yes, there is of course variations depending on the table layouts, and also how much data there is and how varied it is.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I looked at your answer properly. Specifically the last line of the query. It turns out the query the OP asked the question about is not the actual one where he is seeing the behaviour he wants explained anyway though...

Answer (score 2):

A dramatic comparison, let's say this...

```
select columnB
from table2
```

...has billion rows (30 seconds), many data travels the wire and presented to user.

And this...

```
select columnA 
from table1
```

...has only one row.

RDBMS won't do a dumb job of pulling the data of table2 from server to client if you don't intend to display the data of table2. So no network bandwidth or I/O will be involved much when doing data presence testing, it all happens at the server, the only thing that would be pulled from server to client is the one row of table1 only.

```
select columnA 
from table1
where columnA not in (
select columnB
from table2)
```

And things shall be especially fast if your columnA and columnB happen to have an index

Things that would make a database operation slow are twofold: first is when you pull too much data from the server to client, second is when you don't have an index on pertinent fields

Comment: @Aleksandar You say your query only returns 50 rows though.

Comment: @Aleksandar - Well can you post your **actual** queries and table definitions rather than over simplified versions.

Answer (score 0):

When it can make use of indexes and the number of returned results is small. It might be. Returning the results can cause execution time.

Answer (score 0):

just going to chime in, make sure that you are aware of the difference between [NOT In and NOT EXISTS](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/01/21/32/).

If "columnA" is NULL, it won't be returned via the NOT IN solution you are looking at, but the LEFT antijoin examples already presented will behave as NOT EXISTS.

Also, make sure that TOAD/SQL Developer are not 'just showing the top 50' which they like to do (do a select count(*) from table1 to see if 50 is indeed the query result).

do an EXPLAIN PLAN on the query and see if it highlights anything that looks egregious -- check your indexes and also see if the columns allow NULLS -- lack of indexes may be the culprit but a full table scan from NULLS may be causing the nightmare).

Comment: thanks Harrison, I'm aware of all the things you mentioned. checking the explain plan now to see if it helps...

Answer (score -1):

NOT is a performance killer.

On some SQL engine does first the in(...) into a temporary table the re-run the query doing a NOT on the datas in the temporary table.

If you can, you should use IN only !

Comment: But @Aleksandar wondered why the question congaing the **performance killer** was so fast.

Comment: NOT IN **can** be brutally efficient. If the columns on both side of the operator are defined as NOT NULL, NOT IN opens very efficient access paths (HASH ANTI JOIN, NESTED LOOP ANTI JOIN...). This is probably what happens in the OP's query. Think about it: if a feature was always bad it would be removed.

Comment: It can yes, using index is better but not every time too (think about too)

Comment: Saying that "NOT is a performance killer" is (a) an over-generalization, and (b) irrelevant to the actual question being asked.

Comment: Ok, ok NOT is SOMETIMES a performance killer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756361/avoiding-sql-not-in-by-using-replace-and-length-check